# Java-Swing: Change getSource() in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I have a class that contains a JButton. This can't be changed.

The problem is this: The actionListener calls getSource() and gets the JButton, not the container class.

Can I change what getSource retrieves, before the actionListener is added?
OR can JButtons have a variable reference to its container?

I can't make a class extend a JButton. It caused bugs for drawing purposes... story of my week.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do you click a button and therefore generate an ActionEvent, if it hasn't been added to the GUI? Sounds like a wierd design to me. I also fail to see why extending a JButton will cause painting problems. Again you have done something wierd in your code. You need to address these issues first. Post your SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

See `JButton.getParent()`

Comment: The object it is contained in isn't a Component, it just stored a JButton object, along with other data.

getParent therefore won't return the Object that contains the JButton.

Any other way you know to have a button reference something, or to override the JButton's ActionListener functinos, that provide a "source"?

Comment: How about setting the name (setName) or the actionCommand (setActionCommand). Then use that to retrieve the container from a globally accessible map?

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to add context to the listener than to use `getSource`.

Answer (score 1):

For attaching arbitrary data to any JComponent, use [putClientProperty(Object key, Object value)][1], then in your listener, call [getClientProperty(Object key)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty(java.lang.Object)) to retrieve the value.

[1]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)